# weird behavior of sheepit renderfarm

Tags: rendering, sheepit

Recently I notice the weird behavior of sheepit renderfarm client. It appears when the client works within a couple hours.
"Project to check rendering capabilities" For half an hour render time?! I know its sound paranoid but its looks like mining. [image]

Comment: This looks like an advertisement rather than a question.

Comment: You can review and build the code if you want be sure https://github.com/laurent-clouet/sheepit-client

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about third party services

Comment: That's sounds reasonable, however SheepIt is a free service dediceated only to Blender Cycles. This looks similar to any other questions about specific Blender addons or export to other software to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. It displays the last rendered frame while rendering another one. You can see the name of the currently rendering project - it is not the test project that is rendering.

[image]